# Meteor: Error while updating document

Tags: mongodb, meteor, momentjs

I get an error while updating date of an object

```
Template.showCards.events({
    ...
    },
    'click #difficulty button': function(event) {
        var incBy = event.target.value;
        var today = moment();
        var newDue = moment(today).add(incBy,'days');
        Cards.update(
            this._id, {
                $set: {due: newDue}
                }
            );
    }
});
```

Any idea why?

Meteor updates the correct `due` field but the value becomes `"Invalid date"`.

Here is the full error (Chrome Dev tools):

```
Exception while simulating the effect of invoking '/cards/update' Error: Sorting not supported on regular expression {stack: (...), message: "Sorting not supported on regular expression"} Error: Sorting not supported on regular expression
    at Error (native)
    at Object.LocalCollection._f._cmp (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:2411:13)
    at Object.LocalCollection._f._cmp (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:2386:36)
    at Object.LocalCollection._f._cmp (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:2378:33)
    at Object.LocalCollection._f._cmp (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:2386:36)
    at Object.LocalCollection._f._cmp (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:2378:33)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:1838:54
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:1474:21
    at Array.some (native)
    at Function._.some._.any (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:284:59)
```

Comment: what happens when you log "incBy" in the event handler? could it be a string/integer problem that just needs `parseInt`?

Comment: @richsilv thanks for your reply! It is a string. I made a change: `var incBy = parseInt(event.target.value);` but it's still the same problem. It seems like it doesn't matter if its a string or int.

Comment: Ah yes, that may be irrelevant. See below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to store a Moment.js object in the DB rather than a Javascript date object, which you can't do.  You need to retrieve the underlying JS date object like so:

```
var newDue = moment(today).add(incBy,'days').toDate();
```

Comment: That works, but it wonders me. I got fixture data like this: ...    var today = moment();     Cards.insert({
        deckName: meteorId,
        due: today,
        front: 'blaa',
        back: 'blaa blaa'
    });
And my fixture data works properly. Date is stored as moment object. (due: Object_d: Tue Jan 06 2015 21:01:30 GMT+0200 (EET)_isAMomentObject: true_isUTC: false_locale: Object_pf: Object__proto__: Object)